# How to define an Excel macro using C#

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I have a problem about how to define Excel macros via C# code. 
For example, I create a button in Excel, and then assign a C# function to it as its macro function instead of using VBA. Can anybody give me some point?? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Article that explains what you are trying to do I hope this helps

[Excel Macro -Create and Run at Runtime using C#](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/create_macro_at_runtime_in_dotnet.asp)

Comment: Actually I read it before but it doesn't help... However thanks very much guys.